# Ubuntu 14.04: Watching videos in fullscreen (browser/vlc) freezes the whole system

Tags: 14.04, video, freeze, fullscreen

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and this is my first experience with Linux. I've tried watching videos on Mozilla and Chrome, and also playing in VLC, the problem persists. I go full-screen, it works fine for about 30min and then it freezes, no interaction possible. I have no choice but to force it to shut down.

If it makes any difference, here's what I'm using:

Lenovo G50-30 with Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

- CPU: 4x Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU N3530 @ 2.16GHz
- 2GB PC3-10600 DDR3L SDRAM 1333 MHz
- Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co.
- Ltd. RTL8723BE, GPU:Intel® HD Graphics

EDIT: after using 'chromium-browser|& tee -a chromium.txt' the log reads
 [1:1:0608/033420:ERROR:PlatformKeyboardEvent.cpp(84)] Not implemented reached in static bool blink::PlatformKeyboardEvent::currentCapsLockState()
[1:1:0608/033443:ERROR:PlatformKeyboardEvent.cpp(117)] Not implemented reached in static blink::PlatformEvent::Modifiers blink::PlatformKeyboardEvent::getCurrentModifierState()
[1:1:0608/033529:ERROR:PlatformKeyboardEvent.cpp(117)] Not implemented reached in static blink::PlatformEvent::Modifiers
(it goes on like this for a while, and then)
blink::PlatformKeyboardEvent::getCurrentModifierState()

Comment: Run vlc or chromium with the command `chromium-browser| tee chromium.txt` (chromium needs to be closed before so that it won't use the existing chromium session) and this will create a chromium.txt file at your home folder with the output of the command, so when you experience the freeze you can access it after reboot and paste the contents to your question to see what errors it has.

Comment: I tried this and after reboot, the file was blank. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry my bad, you need to use `chromium-browser|& tee -a chromium.txt` to get the errors.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what these errors are. Copy the contents of the file here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and provide a link to your question and hope that someone else can help you...